# Graphviz: Online tool capable of accepting larger files

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization

Does anyone know of a good online site for rendering graphviz dot files that will take larger files (say, 200 lines; 200 nodes )?

I was using http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/ & it used to work fine so far but the moment I cross about 100 lines it seems to throw errors. Can someone else check maybe?

Comment: Image-charts (1 URL = 1 graph svg image) handles GraphViz as well, with a limit of up to 400 edges https://documentation.image-charts.com/graph-viz-charts/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GraphvizOnline
http://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/
Edit and render the dot file online

Comment: Fantastic tool. You wrote it? I love the syntax highlighting! You should write one that can dynamically view dot files!

Comment: @curious_cat I'm glad to hear you like it. IDK dot supports the multi files render. If you just want a drag file feature in the browser, that's easy to approach.

Comment: Yes. It would be nice to be able to zoom / pan / highlight etc. within the browser.

Comment: The tool hangs in a few cases. Can you have a look? I can send you the dot file I was trying to render if it helps!

Comment: Hi @curious_cat , I saw the issue ticket. Cause this tool was created three years ago, maybe some features that don't support. I will upgrade the graphviz interpreter when I get a chance.

Comment: Hmmm...thanks. Where does one submit an issue ticket? That wasn't by me. I will submit mine too.

Comment: It seems once I hit graphs beyond a certain size the tool gets caught in a "rendering" loop. I'm talking of tens of nodes not hundreds or thousands so not an unusually large use case for graphviz.

Comment: It seems unable to render labels with HTML entities, such as `[label="&epsilon;"]`

Comment: @AlexReinking I fixed a non-ASCII issue as you mentioned.

Comment: @Dreampuf Thanks! I'm using your tool to help students visualize NFAs for our course in compilers. Much nicer than having them each get graphviz installed locally.

Comment: Despite all the upvotes, this answer is incorrect, as "abort("Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 16777216, (2) compile with -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 which allows increasing the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY to a higher value before the program runs, or (4) if you want malloc to return NULL (0) instead of this abort, compile with -s ABORTING_MALLOC=0 "). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info."

Comment: @user1095332 Thank you for the comment. I think I can make a new backend as `ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1`. The memory usage depends on how big your input is. But please be aware that there will be a hardware level limitation in any way.

Answer (score 5):

There's the Graphviz [renderer build](https://viz-js.com/) of the original `viz.js` repo. According to the description it's:

> ... a Makefile for building Graphviz with Emscripten and a simple wrapper for using it in the browser.

So I would expect most Graphviz's features. Though it couldn't render [this 8K .dot file](https://gist.github.com/williame/4087256) complaining about limit of 16MiB (can be configured). Reducing the size I have got it rendered first 1K lines without an error.

Comment: Out of the three tools currently listed in answers here, I would say this is the best. It's very similar to Dreampuf's tool (the accepted answer) but also supports zooming and panning of the result and resizing of the two panels which helps make the tool a bit more usable.

Comment: All the posted solutions including this one are incorrect, as they are all 3 using viz.js without compiling with "ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH"

Comment: URL doesn't work.

Comment: The renderer's [repo](https://github.com/mdaines/viz-js) now points to https://viz-js.com/ instead of GitHub Pages. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This online tool by HermannSW works great with arbitrary sized files:

http://stamm-wilbrandt.de/GraphvizFiddle/

For documentation see here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/HermannSW/entry/graphvizfiddle?lang=en

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as "viz.js:1 Uncaught Assertion: Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value ( 10485760), (2) compile with ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, or (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY before the program runs."