# List Jenkins plugins and dependencies (with graph)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dot

I have added many plugins to Jenkins. How can I list the plugins and dependencies? Which plugins depend on which ones? Which ones are orphaned or unused, etc.

Ideally, explain how to make a graph (graphviz/dot...) ?

Answer (score 24):

Copy-paste this groovy snippet to get a list of plugins (this snippet based on [this exemple from zendesk.com](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/216351528-How-Do-I-Analyse-Plugins-and-Dependencies-for-an-Instance)):

Note: the groovy must be pasted in _Manage Jenkins >> Script Console

```
def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
plugins.each {
    println "${it.getShortName()} (${it.getVersion()}) => ${it.getDependencies()}"
}
```

To produce a graph, execute this snippet to generate a [DOT graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) (graphviz) file...

```
def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
println "digraph test {"
plugins.each {
    def plugin = it.getShortName()
    println "\"${plugin}\";"
    def deps =  it.getDependencies()
    deps.each {
      def s = it.shortName
      println "\"${plugin}\" -> \"${s}\";"
    }
} 
println "}"
```

Then use graphviz to generate an image from the output above:

```
dot -Tsvg  plugins.txt > plugins.svg
dot -Tpng  plugins.txt > plugins.png
```

Or copy-paste the output in one of the  [Graphviz: Online tool capable of accepting larger files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28241149/1260896)

Comment: Is there a way to know the required version of a dependency? As I understand getVersion only list the installed version.

Comment: Maybe you should add the T before png. It's rather obvious, but so the command is correct ;)